# Convert UTC to EST in Query [MS SQL]

Tags: sql-server

Long time reader first time poster :)

I am making a query that has a date formatted like this **2022-03-01T04:59:59.000+0000** since this is in UTC I need to get it into EST. I am having issues converting this. I have tried a few things I found online. The closest I have gotten is this.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 
             SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, 
                                   convert(varchar, [UTC Date Field], 1)), 
                            DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) 
AS ColumnInLocalTime
from [Table Name] a (nolock)
```

But this is giving me an *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.* error. I am using MS SQL Server and I would consider my self competent in SQL. I know the data in the field I am using is stored as varchar. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Side point: `NOLOCK` is a bad idea and has serious data integrity implications, you shouldn't use it unless you *really* know what you're doing

Comment: For SQL Server 2017+ consider [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql). Separate from *starting* at a valid DATETIME-ish kind.

Comment: `select cast(left('2022-03-01T04:59:59.000+0000', 23)+'Z' as datetime2(3)) at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'eastern standard time';`

Comment: And if you're going to use hints, at least use current syntax and not deprecated syntax!

Comment: @Charlieface Our team is always using NOLOCK. We are only doing queries on the data. And the data sources updated once over night. I was told to add the NOLOCK so it will not lock the tables for other users.

Comment: I am new at asking the forum for help. Is this what you are after when posting? Will not let me (at) more than once.
---
declare (at)utc_time varchar(255)
set (at)utc_time = '2022-03-01T04:59:59.000+0000'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 
               SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, 
                                   convert(varchar, @utc_time, 1)), 
                            DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) 
AS ColumnInLocalTime

Comment: It's just the wrong solution for almost all blocking problems, and it's a myth that it will never lock. Firstly, it can cause all manner of incorrect data, including but not limited to: reading rows, or even whole pages, multiple times or not at all; data failing primary, unique, foreign or check constraints; doubled up joins which were supposed to be unique; data that makes no sense either before or after other transactions; LOB data that is completely corrupt; at times random error # 601. And you *still* get blocking if there is any DDL at the same time, .....

Comment: .... such as index rebuilds or statistics updates. If there are no concurrent readers/writers then you should just use a `TABLOCK` hint and get the same performance advantage. If there is concurrent access (eg in your case) then you should use `SNAPSHOT` isolation. `NOLOCK` is the wrong tool for almost any job involving databases, it should be used purely as a diagnostic tool. It's [cargo-cultism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) in the extreme [to just slap it everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed info. I will bring it up with my team. That is all news to me. No formal training here just learned OTJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value is not in a ISO8601 format that SQL Server recognizes, it's missing a `:` in the time zone part.

**Let's just say you wouldn't have had this issue if your data would have been stored as `datetimeoffset` in the first place.**

You can patch it up using `STUFF`, then just `CONVERT` with style `126`

```sql
SELECT
  SWITCHOFFSET(
    CONVERT(datetimeoffset,
      STUFF('2022-03-01T04:59:59.000+0000', 27, 0, ':'),
      126),
    DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
  )
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f468419638108ba4b3f5c8c4a1e45652)

Comment: Thanks so much. And I now know how to STUFF it.